# How can I download an entire website?

Tags: software-recommendation

I want to download a whole website (with sub-sites). Is there any tool for that?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? the title and the content of your question are not related, and the content is not specific.

Comment: N.B., only following links (e.g., using `--convert-links` in wget) will not reveal sites that are only revealed by submitting a form, among other things.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Try example 10 from [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/the-ultimate-wget-download-guide-with-15-awesome-examples/):

```
wget --mirror -p --convert-links -P ./LOCAL-DIR WEBSITE-URL
```

- `–mirror` : turn on options suitable
  for mirroring.
- `-p` : download all files that are necessary to properly display a given
  HTML page.
- `--convert-links` : after the
  download, convert the links in
  document for local viewing.
- `-P ./LOCAL-DIR` : save all the files and directories to the specified
  directory.

Comment: is there any way to download only certain pages (for instance, several parts of an articles that is spread over several html documents)?

Comment: @Private Yes, although it's probably easier to use python or something to get the pages (depending on the layout/url). If the url of the pages differs by a constantly growing number or you have a list of the pages, you could probably use wget in a bash script.

Comment: You might consider using the `--wait=seconds` argument if you want to be more friendly to the site ; it will wait the specified number of seconds between retrievals.

Comment: the above works, but for joomla the parameterized url creates files that are not linked locally.
The one worked for me is wget -m -k -K -E http://your.domain.com 
from here: https://vaasa.hacklab.fi/2013/11/28/howto-make-a-static-copy-of-joomla-site-with-wget/

Comment: Also `--no-parent` to "never ascend to the parent directory" taken from [here](https://superuser.com/a/487206/372305).

Comment: Gotta love stackoverflow's oneliner accepted answers <3

Answer (score 43):

[image: HTTrack for Linux copying websites in offline mode]

[httrack](http://packages.ubuntu.com/httrack) is the tool you are looking for.

> [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) allows you to download a World Wide Web site from the Internet to a local directory, building recursively all directories, getting HTML, images, and other files from the server to your computer. HTTrack arranges the original site's relative link-structure.

Answer (score 11):

With `wget` you can download an entire website, you should use `-r` switch for a **recursive** download. For example,

```
wget -r http://www.google.com
```

Answer (score 7):

**WEBHTTRACK WEBSITE COPIER** is a handy tool to download a whole website onto your hard disk for offline browsing. Launch ubuntu software center and type "webhttrack website copier" without the quotes into the search box. select and download it from the software center onto your system. start the webHTTrack from either the laucher or the start menu, from there you can begin enjoying this great tool for your site downloads

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about sub domains, i.e, sub-sites, but wget can be used to grab a complete site. Take a look at the [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/130306/suggestions-for-a-site-ripper). 
It says that you can use `-D domain1.com,domain2.com` to download different domains in single script. I think you can use that option to download sub-domains i.e `-D site1.somesite.com,site2.somesite.com`

Answer (score 2):

I use [Burp](http://portswigger.net/burp/) - the spider tool is much more intelligent than wget, and can be configured to avoid sections if necessary. The Burp Suite itself is a powerful set of tools to aid in testing, but the spider tool is very effective.

Comment: Isn't Burp Windows Only? The closed-source licence agreement for Burp is also quite heavy. Not to mention the price tag $299.00:

Comment: from the licence:
WARNING: BURP SUITE FREE EDITION IS DESIGNED TO TEST FOR SECURITY FLAWS AND CAN DO DAMAGE TO TARGET SYSTEMS DUE TO THE NATURE OF ITS FUNCTIONALITY. TESTING FOR SECURITY FLAWS INHERENTLY INVOLVES INTERACTING WITH TARGETS IN NON-STANDARD WAYS WHICH CAN CAUSE PROBLEMS IN SOME VULNERABLE TARGETS. YOU MUST TAKE DUE CARE WHEN USING THE SOFTWARE, YOU MUST READ ALL DOCUMENTATION BEFORE USE, YOU SHOULD BACK UP TARGET SYSTEMS BEFORE USE AND YOU SHOULD NOT USE THE SOFTWARE ON PRODUCTION SYSTEMS OR OTHER SYSTEMS FOR WHICH THE RISK OF DAMAGE IS NOT ACCEPTED BY YOU.

Comment: For what it does, the price tag is amazingly cheap - I would recommend buying it for a wide range of security testing. And it is very easy to configure it to test exactly as you want - safer than AppScan in some instances:-)

Comment: @KatAmsterdam Regarding specifically the compatibility question: [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burp_suite), Burp Suite is a Java application, so it *should* run fine on Ubuntu.

Comment: Kat - it runs just fine on various flavours of Linux. The warning on the licence is the same as any tool you can use for security assessments.

Answer (score 2):

You can download Entire Website
Command :

```
wget -r -l 0 website
```

Example :

```
wget -r -l 0 http://google.com
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this command works? What it does?

Comment: @KazWolfe `-r` turns on recursive retrieving with a default depth of 5 levels. `-l` specifies the maximum recursion depth which is in this example 0.

Answer (score 1):

If speed is a concern (and the server's wellbeing is not), you can try [puf](http://puf.sourceforge.net/), which works like *wget* but can download several pages in parallel. It is, however, not a finished product, not maintained and horribly undocumented. Still, for to download a web site with lots and lots of smallish files, this might be a good option.