# Download a website

Tags: downloads

I want to download this webpage located deep: `example.com/a/b/c/d` The problem that I am having is that `wget --recursive --page-requisites example.com/a/b/c/d` does not download the css or js files. It only downloads a single html file.

Comment: Perhaps this might be useful: https://askubuntu.com/q/20463/57576

Answer (score 0):

Per this page:

[Downloading an Entire Web Site with wget](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/downloading-entire-web-site-wget)

```
 wget \
     --recursive \
     --no-clobber \
     --page-requisites \
     --html-extension \
     --convert-links \
     --restrict-file-names=windows \
     --domains website.org \
     --no-parent \
         www.website.org/tutorials/html/
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, no this does not work. it only downloads a simple file, renames it with a html extension. but the depending css, js files are not downloaded at all

Comment: bummer... you might have to write a script that accomplishes this